# PHP - Can't listen for submit button press

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to build a simple HTML form that is spread over two pages. 
First page asks for user's first and last name. Second page asks for his country & whether he would like to receive additional info.

The first page has a single button named "Next" for going to the second page. The second page has two buttons named "Next" to go the next page (non-existent at present) and "Back" to go back to the first page.

On the first page when I click the "Next" button, nothing happens. How can I go to the next page on clicking it ?

Here is my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        if(!isset($_POST['next1']))
            Display1();
        else if(isset($_POST['next1']))
            Display2();
        else if(isset($_POST['back1']))
            Display1();
    ?>
    <?php
        function Display1()
        {
    ?>
    <form id="form1" action="Multi.php" method="post">
    <label>Enter First Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="text1"  />
    <br />
    <br />
    <label>Enter Last Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="text2"  />
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="button" name="next1" value="Next" />
    <?php
    }
    function Display2()
    {
    ?>
        <form id="form2" action="Multi.php" method="post">
        Select Country
        <select name="country[]" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="India">India</option>
        <option value="USA">USA</option>
        <option value="China">China</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <br />
        Do you want to receive latest info ?
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1[]"  />Yes
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="button" name="next2" value="Next" />
        <input type="button" name="back1" value="Back" />
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The input type needs to be "submit"

```
 <input type="submit" name="next1" value="Next" />
```

So for all the inputs that has "button" you need to change to "submit"

Comment: also in the second if statement, should check for 'next2' not 'next1'

Answer (score 1):

And as an addition to Abhik's answer.

`<input type="button">` is only a clickable input. You (mostly) use it when you want to call a JS script. So if for some obscure reason you want to use this instead of the more simple solution provided by Abhik go ahead and add a `onclick` event handler.

```
<input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById("form1").submit();">
```

You could also use a `<button>` instead, but make sure you **always** specify the `type`. The advantage is that they offer a higher degree of customization. Basically you can put HTML inside a `<button>` tag.

So try also:

```
<button type="submit" value="Next">Next</button>
```

The other types of buttons are (source: [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp)):

- button: The button is a clickable button
- submit: The button is a submit button (submits form-data)
- reset: The button is a reset button (resets the form-data to its initial values)